# c# pdf How to set textfield label with iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf file I am trying to add a new textfield to. So far i have been able to add the textfield, however i have not been able to add the label that precedes it.
E.g., if i want to insert a "Name" field, i would like to display it as shown below 
Name:____________
After the colon is the actual textfield and "Name" would represent the label for the field.

So far i am only able to insert the textfield without the label. Below is the code I am using.
Can somebody please tell me if i am missing something from my code?

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out1);

TextField tf = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x, h, w, y), "User Name:");

tf.FieldName = "User Name:";                

stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), page_num);
```

Option #2
Below is the second option that I tried with the same results.

```
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, false, false,50);

//Set the dimensions for the new field
field.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x, h, w, y), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE);

field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
field.FieldName = "User Name";

stamper.AddAnnotation(field, page_num);
```

Comment: "Labels" essentially are regular page content. Thus, simply add the label to the OverContent of the PdfStamper.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I was under the assumption that by adding a textfield with the field name, that the label will display the value of the field name.

Comment: Is this correct? 
I used the OverContent but the label value was not displayed.

Comment: you draw the text using the over content. I'll go for an example in office tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label of a field in PDF is not contained in some dedicated label object, it is mere page content. Thus, it has to be added as regular content.

I merely have Java development tools at my hand right now, so the following sample is in Java for iText. (Usually such code is easy to translate to C# code for iTextSharp, mostly by replacing getter and setter calls by property access.)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, TARGET); 

TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(300, 400, 500, 420), "UserName");
stamper.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField(), 1);

PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont();
overContent.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
overContent.beginText();
overContent.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "User Name:", 300, 405, 0);
overContent.endText();

stamper.close ();
```

Comment: This worked. So moving forward, i will have to insert text for each textfield i insert.
Thanks

Comment: @user3852972 *This worked.* - That's great. Thus, you may want to mark the answer as *accepted answer.*